# Laravel redirect after successful login

Tags: laravel-5

I have created 2 extra Auth methods. When I use the regular Auth method a URL like /dashboard/pages/edit/1 will prompt for a login and after successful login the user is redirected to the initial URL instead of /dashboard/pages. But the other method like /secure/page will redirect the user to /secure after login is successful.

My LoginController has this:

```
public function redirectPath() {
    if (\Auth::user()->user_type_id <= 2) {
        return '/dashboard/pages';
    } else {
        if(\Auth::user()->user_type_id == 3) {
            return '/shop';
        } else {
            return '/secure';
        }
    }
}
```

RedirectIfAuthenticated.php:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if ($this->auth->check()) {
        if (\Auth::user()->user_type_id <= 2) {
            return new RedirectResponse(url('/dashboard/pages'));
        } else {
            if(\Auth::user()->user_type_id == 3) {
                return new RedirectResponse(url('/shop'));
            } else {
                return new RedirectResponse(url('/secure'));
            }
        }

    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

The redirects all work, except the referrer

Comment: what do you mean when you say referer, is that the link or the user? and how it doesnt work? what were you expecting and what was the outcome?

Comment: Well it's like this... I am not logged in to the back end and when I use a URL like /dashboard/pages/edit/1 (the referrer), I am redirected to the login form at /auth/login. After a successful login, I am redirected to /dashboard/pages/edit/1?page=dashboard%2Fpages%2Fedit%2F1 as everything behind /dashboard should have a valid auth. But when I access /secure/page/1 (the referrer) while not being logged in, I am not redirected to the referrer after login, but just land on page /secure